# MVC View Does Not Contain Expected Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view(EditView) that should display the data from 2 models. For this I put 2 models in one class like

```
public class MergeModel
{
    public Reservation Reservation { get; set; }
    public ViewTrain ViewTrain { get; set; }

}
```

and in the view I put the first line as `@model MergeModel`. But my problem is I'm sending only `ViewTrain` model's data to `EditView` and not Reservation model's data, so its displaying a error like the view is expecting `MergeModel` but you are sending `ViewTrain` model. So what should I do now to solve this?
In detail: I have a ViewTrain model which contains trainId,TrainName,StartPlace and EndPlace and I have Reservation model which contains ReserveId,trainId,TrainName,StartPlace,EndPlace,NeedNoOfSeats. I have a view in which if I enter startPlace and EndPlace it will show the relevant trains available. On a particular train detail, if i click on select option a new view should be rendered in which all these details like trainId,TrainName,StartPlace and endPlace should be autofilled and NeedNoOfSeats textbox should be available to enter the number of seats, but Im not able do this..

Comment: you might need to elaborate a bit more and perhaps include some sample code; questions like this usually get downvoted

Comment: How are you populating the view model in your action?

Comment: In the controller, you are returning the wrong Model to the View. So if you add the controller action code to the question, it is easier to show you what to change.

Comment: Also, you can´t return two different Models to one View, but instead use Partial Views in the Html

Comment: @Mikael,  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult EditReservation(int TrainId)
        {
            TrainBusinessLayer trainBusinessLayer = new TrainBusinessLayer();
            ViewTrain viewtrain = trainBusinessLayer.ViewTrains.Single(x => x.TrainId == TrainId);
            return View(viewtrain);
        }

Answer (score 1):

1) You should add Constructor method to MergeModel Class

```
public MergeModel()
    {
        Reservation = new Reservation();
        ViewTrain = new ViewTrain();
    }
```

2) In the action method you should return a MergModel object

```
MergeModel model=new MergeModel();  
//fill data to model  
return View(model);
```

Comment: My action method is like this------> [HttpGet] public ActionResult EditReservation(int TrainId) { TrainBusinessLayer trainBusinessLayer = new TrainBusinessLayer(); ViewTrain viewtrain = trainBusinessLayer.ViewTrains.Single(x => x.TrainId == TrainId); return View(viewtrain); }  How can I return MergeModel Object?

Comment: delete your return line and add followings.

Comment: MergeModel model=new MergeModel();  
model.ViewTrain=viewtrain;
return View(model);

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the class `Reservation` might be null, create a instance of that class.

Like this -

```
new MergeModel{ new Reservation(), new ViewTrain() };
```

Hope this helps, if doesn't then post more details.